# How to test exceptions with doctest in Python 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, python-2.x, doctest

I defined an exception class `SpamException` in a module `spam`. Now I want to test a function `spam_function`, that raises this exception. So I wrote the following doctest.

```
>>> spam_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
SpamException
```

The test succeeds on Python 2.x, but on Python 3.x the test fails. The following test works on Python 3.x.

```
>>> spam_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
spam.SpamException
```

The notable difference here is the inclusion of the module name in the exception name. So how can I write a doctest that works on both Python 2.x and 3.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would turn on the [`doctest.IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL) directive, like this:

```
>>> spam_function() # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
Traceback (most recent call last)
    ...
SpamException: 'lovely spam'
```

But note that `IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` doesn't work for plain exception objects (with no associated arguments). In particular, the following example isn't portable to Python 3, because there's nothing following the exception name:

```
>>> spam_function() # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
Traceback (most recent call last)
    ...
SpamException
```

Comment: I did not notice any change when adding `# doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL`, i.e. it keeps failing with either Python version. Can you add a complete example?

Comment: The `IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` works as soon as the exception class in question has a `__str__` method that returns a non-empty string. Then and only then the final exception line has a colon, that is required for the directive to work.

Comment: It seems that IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL ignores also the exception message, which removes a great part of the purpose of doctesting these behavior. But the exception type is still checked. ouf !