# python 2.7, 3.x doctest compatibility vs FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When writing doctests and examples for code that should work in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x, [we typically use `# doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` to paper over differences between Python 2.x and 3.x tracebacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17671147/1256452).  This takes care of `BarError` vs `music.BarError`, for instance—but it falls apart for `OSError(errno.ENOENT, ...)` and `IOError(errno.ENOENT, ...)`, because, well, see:

```
import errno

def testme():
    """
    Test doctest vs ENOENT

    >>> testme()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    OSError: [Errno 2] so far so good
    """
    raise OSError(errno.ENOENT, 'so far so good')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

When this is run with python2.7, all is well:

```
$ python2 test3.py -v
Trying:
    testme()
Expecting:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    OSError: [Errno 2] so far so good
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.testme
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

When run with Python 3.x, however:

```
$ python3 test3.py
**********************************************************************
File "test3.py", line 7, in __main__.testme
Failed example:
    testme()
Expected:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    OSError: [Errno 2] so far so good
Got:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest __main__.testme[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        testme()
      File "test3.py", line 12, in testme
        raise OSError(errno.ENOENT, 'so far so good')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] so far so good
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.testme
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Python 3.6 replaces `OSError` with `FileNotFoundError`.

The same thing happens with `IOError`.  File `test4.py` has `OSError` replaced with `IOError` in the `raise` and the docstring.  Without quoting everything:

```
$ python2 test4.py
$ python3 test4.py
...
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] so far so good
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Using `IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` does not help, because (apparently) that only skips the prefix up through the `.` before the first colon in the error message, and here the problem is the string literals `OSError` and `IOError` vs `FileNotFoundError`.

I have a decorator-based solution I'll include as an answer, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a decorator-based solution that is not the prettiest thing ever:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    def enoent_doc(func):
        "py3k compat around ENOENT"
        func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.replace('OS:ENOENT',
            'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]').replace('IO:ENOENT',
            'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]')
        return func
else:
    def enoent_doc(func):
        "py2k compat around ENOENT"
        func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.replace('OS:ENOENT',
            'OSError: [Errno 2]').replace('IO:ENOENT',
            'IOError: [Errno 2]')
        return func

@enoent_doc
def testme():
    """
    Test doctest vs ENOENT

    >>> testme()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    OS:ENOENT so far so good
    """
    raise OSError(errno.ENOENT, 'so far so good')
```

Now the code can be run in either python2 (2.7) or python3 (3.x).

The decorator could be a bit cleverer (not hardcoding `2` as the `[Errno]` value for instance), but it works.

Is there a better fix?